# How to get two divs of different widths below each other inside another div that is floating

Tags: html, css

I have a div structure that is experiencing some issues.

I have "rows", almost like a table but made with divs. Each div row has 2 divs, essentially like 2 div columns. Each column just has some filler text. The issue is that the second row div, is actually on top of the first row div. It's confusing because the content in the second row sits exactly where it should be if the second row were to be sitting where it it actually supposed to be... however using inline styling I have discovered the rows are not positioned correctly and that they are just actually stacking.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="green">
    <div class="title">div1</div>
        <div class="wrapper">
          div2
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="background:red">
    <div class="title">div3</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      div4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  width:100%;
  background:rgb(133, 133, 133);
  height:100px;
}

.row{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}

.title{
  width:20%;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
}

.wrapper{
  float:left;
  width:80%;
  height:50px;
}
```

A link to an image to help explain what I want is here... https://i.imgur.com/GawSC4y.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing the closing `div` tag on the first row.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="background:green">
    <div class="title">div1</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      div2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="background:red">
    <div class="title">div3</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      div4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I feel so silly right now... You are right. My logic was right all along, it was just a typo.

Comment: Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes, don't feel sill.

Answer (score 0):

Is this wat u want?

Floated elements parents need to be clearfixed.

use

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  clear:both;/*Add this*/
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(133, 133, 133);
  height: 100px;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  clear:both;
}

.title {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="background:green">
    <div class="title">div1</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      div2
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background:red">
      <div class="title">div3</div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        div4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```